# Equivalent annotation when migrating swagger 1.5.x to 2.2.x

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am stuck with a version compatibility issue between `springboot 2.6.x` and `springfox 2.9.2`. I tried multiple solutions but nothing seems to work thus defaulting back to the suggestions from Spring where we need to migrate `springfox` to `springdoc`

I am updating all the swagger annotation as suggested [here](https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springfox).

In my old annotation of `@ApiResponse` I am using `response` as below:

```
@ApiResponses(value = [
    ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successful", response = MyResponse::class)
```

Swagger 2.x.x does not seem to have any alternative to `response` that I have as above.

Any suggestions on what can be used instead to maintain the same behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

Posting for others.
It can be done in the following manner:

```
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Successful",
    content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = MyResponse.class)))
```